# Add a PWA application to Firefox desktop

Tags: firefox, progressive-web-apps

In Google Chrome / Chromium I can add a PWA application to the applications screen `chrome://apps/` is there a similar feature in Firefox desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Mozilla, "there is currently no plan for PWA support in Firefox". You can see more about this issue on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1682593#c8).